# DOMDocument : Find div, get contents and print without div

Tags: php, wordpress, domdocument

I would like to use DOMDocument or another proposed method to do the following in wordpess:

I have this html saved in a variable:

```
<div id="gallery-3232" class="gallery gallery-3232">
<li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
</div>
```

And I would like to end up with a variable containing that:

```
<li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
```

How can I do this but without javascript. With the use of PHP.

Thabnk you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$source = '<div id="gallery-3232" class="gallery gallery-3232">
            <li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
            </div>';

$list = new DOMDocument();
$list->loadHTML($source);

$listItems = $list->getElementsByTagName('li');

$listString = "";

foreach ($listItems as $list) {
    $listString .= $list->C14N();
}

echo $listString;
```

Comment: I like this answer, much neater. I hadn't seen the C14N function before.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this, I think it's what you require. Basically load the HTML into a DOMDocument, get the element you need by ID and then iterate through its child nodes and output:

```
$html = '<div id="gallery-3232" class="gallery gallery-3232">
<li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
<li><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></li>
</div>
';

$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHtml($html);
$div = $doc->getElementById('gallery-3232');
$output = '';
foreach($div->childNodes as $element)
{
    $output .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHtml($element);
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: Our answers are so similar! I think yours is equally good if I'm honest.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty way using a regex:

```
$string = preg_replace('~</?div[^>]*>~', '', $string);
```

**Note:** like I said, this is a quick and dirty way. If you're sure of your input - use this. However, if you are filtering uncertain input, you'd be better off parsing it properly.

Comment: Great it works!! I understand what you're saying and I would like to parse it more carefully that's why I was investigating DOMDocument but for now its great.